# How to get spot instances for my ElasticBeanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an ElasticBeanstalk environment and set this config

[image: elasticbeanstalk config]

but when I check the status of the instance it shows normal, should not this above config makes the instance a spot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html) explain how to get only spot:

> You may still wish to use a Spot Instance in a single instance environment for development or testing. When you do, be sure to **set both SpotFleetOnDemandBase and SpotFleetOnDemandAboveBasePercentage to zero**. Any other settings result in an On-Demand Instance.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and it worked, the created instance is now Spot